# Looking for a fastest way to treat 3D vectors, their dot products, cross products?

Tags: c++

I am looking for a fastest way to treat 3D vectors (x, y, z) of float type, their dot product, cross product. I think it may go to some intel's technique, such as SSE4. Anyone have a good suggestion? Or experience on how to use SSE4, such as f32vec4? Thanks.

Comment: Don't know anything about it, and never used it but [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) may provide appropriate solutions for you.

Comment: Haven't used it myself, but [Armadillo](http://arma.sourceforge.net/) may be useful to you

Comment: Don't know how well the [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) code is tweaked, but maybe it is useful to you.

Comment: **s.o.** (the OP?) should do some minimal research and put all these comments together to constitute an answer. **Myself:** I'm just too lazy now ;o) ...

Comment: [SSE4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSE4) is bound to a specific CPU oriented instruction set. So the available optimizations for this will well depend on your particular CPU and what the particular compiler toolchain provides.

Answer (score 2):

It was long ago, but the last time I checked out the generated assembler code for this kind of computation the results where quite different depending on the compiler, and even for the very same machine code the execution speed was different depending on the processor.

What I mean is that sometimes what is an optimization in one case is a pessimization in another so it's very difficult to come up with a choice that is always the correct one.

As an example I remember that defining a 3d vector class with

```
struct P3d {
    float x,y,z;
    ...
```

with a compiler the best solution for vector addition for my PC was to define augmented assignments and then define addition using it

```
    ...
    P3d& operator+=(const P3d& other)
    {
        x += other.x;
        y += other.y;
        z += other.z;
        return *this;
    }
 };

 inline P3d operator+(P3d a, const P3d& b)
 {
     a += b;
     return a;
 }
```

and for another compiler instead the best code was generated with the more natural

```
 inline P3d operator+(const P3d& a, const P3d& b)
 {
     return P3d(a.x+b.x, a.y+b.y, a.z+b.z);
 }
```

and sadly enough I found no C++ solution was as fast as writing code by hand for x, y and z explicitly in the formulas.

The differences however were "small" (at most in the order of 20% IIRC) and in the end I just used the version that was most readable.

May be now things are better, but I doubt it. If you really want to squeeze all the juice out then the answer will depend on **exactly** wich compiler version and on **exactly** which processor. This also mean that unless you're coding for a fixed-hardware solution like a console the code will be probably sub-optimal in just a few months when both the compilers and the processors will move on.

Comment: Exactly my thoughts, but without your experience ;o) ...